# Dynamically give HTML element a custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to give a HTML element a new custom attribute?

You know how a "img" html element has the attribute .src:

```
imgEle.src = "";
```

**Can I dynamically give a HTML element my own custom attribute .animationInterval? Is it as simple as this?...**

```
imgEle.animationInterval = setInterval(...,10);
```

Maybe I do it the xml kindof way?...

```
imgEle.setAttribute("animationInterval", setInterval(...));
```

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *best* way is to use html5 `data-` attributes:

```
$(imgEle).attr("data-animateinterval", "12");
```

Which can then be read back with

```
$(imgEle).data("animateinterval");
```

Which of course can also be added directly to your markup

```
<img src="foo.png" data-animateinterval="12" />
```

---

Also, if you're not concerned about whether a new attribute is added to the actual html element, but just want some arbitrary data associated with it, you can simply do this:

```
$(imgEle).data("animateinterval", "12");
```

And retrieve it like this:

```
var animateInterval = $(imgEle).data("animateinterval");
```

Note however that as Esailija explains, this may or may not actually add a new attribute to your element; it may just store this data internally.  If that's not a concern for you, and I can't think of any reasons why it should be, then you may prefer this more succinct syntax.

To be clear, no matter which way you store it, `$(imgEle).data("animateinterval");` will still work just fine.

Comment: @JakeM - it is absolutely, positively cross browser—it even works in IE6.  Enjoy!

Comment: Why aren't you just using `.data` all the way :/

Comment: @Esailija - woulld saying .data("animateinterval", "12") add a new **attribute**, or just store that piece of data on the element internally?

Comment: @AdamRackis it depends, if the element has any events associated with it by jQuery, nothing is added to the element since it already has an id in `jQuery.cache` object. Otherwise an expando property is added to the element object that maps to `jQuery.cache`, which is just a regular js object.

Comment: @Esailija - well op was asking specifically about adding a new attribute, but I'll mention just using .data alone - thank you

Comment: @AdamRackis you'd only need to use attributes when you are dealing with static html markup, if you are in javascript already then you might as well use `.data` to keep the DOM cleaner. Btw it never adds attribute but a property that has `jQuery.expando` as key and the `jQuery.cache` identifier number as value.

Comment: @Esailija - yes, I agree - I added an edit.  Thanks again.  And if you render the element with the data-foo attribute already there, then data("foo") will still work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first way (`element.something`) sets a property and can be anything.

Th second way (`element.setAttribute`) sets an attribute, which must be a string (or serialisable as one via its `toString()` method).

So in this case either way works, but I would recommend the first.